# Loop existing bundles against the current product using Woocommerce Products Bundles

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

All I need is for the bundles to show that's connected to the current product so I can create a loop. I have searched everywhere and can't seem to find the answer.

```
<?php
global $post;
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 99,
    'orderby'        => 'date',
    'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_type',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'bundle',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($query->have_posts()): while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
        $title = get_the_title($post->ID);
        ?>
            <?php echo $title; ?>
                <?php endwhile;?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <div class="col-12 text-center">
                        <h4 class="title">There are currently no bundles for this product.</h4>
                    </div>
                <?php endif;?>
```

I have tried:

```
'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_type',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'bundle',
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: Which plugin did you use for bundled products?

Comment: @VijayHardaha https://woocommerce.com/products/product-bundles/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=marketplace_search_brand_row&utm_content=woocommerce_+product_+bundles&gclid=Cj0KCQiAj4ecBhD3ARIsAM4Q_jE1x34L2xPK_KLB5MVrVNa-_T3t2zovWb21mEohryh4nnENTLz_FbgaAnhgEALw_wcB